# returning defer.promise not working as expected

Tags: angularjs

I've started doing Angular for three days now and I can't wrap my head around the concept of promise.

I'm trying to create a factory to share JSON data between two controllers. The data represent a serialized SQL datatable.

The factory fetches the data using $http

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.factory('Tableau', function ($http, $q) {
    var obj = {};
    obj.getTable = function (page) {
            var temp = {};
            var defer = $q.defer();
            $http.get('api/Table/' + page).then(function (resolve) {
                defer.resolve(resolve.data);
            });
            return defer.promise;
    }
    return obj;
});
```

The first controller should display the data as an HTML table

```
app.controller("TableController", function ($scope, Tableau) {
    $scope.elements = Tableau.getTable(2); // get the first ten rows with row id >= n x 10 (in this case 2 x 10)
});
```

And here's the HTML code with the ng directives

```
<tr ng-repeat="t in elements.myarray track by $index">
    <td ng-repeat="(k,v) in t track by $index">
        <div ng-if="k.indexOf('#')===0">
            <span class="label label-default" ng-repeat="vv in v.split(';')">{{vv}}</span><br />
        </div>
        <div ng-if="k.indexOf('§')===0">
            <a href="{{v}}">Lien</a>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="k.indexOf('#')!=0 && k.indexOf('§')!=0">
            {{v}}
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have no problem calling $http from the controller, but when I moved the code to the factory, $scope.elements contains a promise object instead of my expected JSON object.

I did not implement the second controller, which would create a pagination for the table (using [ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/))

1. How can I wait for $http to complete before returning returning an object from the factory ?
2. If this isn't possible, how can I share data retrieved from a server in a single move ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the promise to complete before using its result. That means using `.then()`:

```
app.controller("TableController", function ($scope, Tableau) {
    Tableau.getTable(2)
        .then(function (result) {
            $scope.elements = result;
        });
});
```

You've also fallen prey to the Explicit Promise Construction Antipattern.

Simpler implementation for your factory:

```
app.factory('Tableau', function ($http, $q) {
    var obj = {};

    obj.getTable = function (page) {
        return $http.get('api/Table/' + page)
            .then(function (result) {
                return result.data;
            });
    };

    return obj;
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and special thanks for the antipattern which I didn't know about.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller:

```
   Tableau.getTable(2)
      .then((data) => {
       $scope.elements = data
    })
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. I marked JLRishe's answer as the accepted answer though, for the additional hint about the Explicit Promise Construction Antipattern.